# Tascam DR-100 MKII: Getting Noise on Some Recordings

Tags: audio-recording, noise, noise-reduction

I just picked up a TASCAM DR-100 MKII the other day and I'm learning how to use it.  Full disclosure, all this sound engineering is brand new to me.  I bought it because I'm going to start doing podcasts and some video review work and I wanted to get a good recording.

Here are my current settings:

- Mode: HS
- Format: WAV 24bit
- Sample: 96K
- Input: Uni/Omni (issue is same on both)
- Mic Gain: H
- Speaker: Off
- Monitor: Off
- Auto/Limiter: Off

I'll set it to record and I can see the levels bouncing.  I'll hit record and on play back, I can hear a buzzing / static sound the whole time.  I can often times adjust it out with the gain control however, sometimes I'll record and hear it then the ***very next recording with ZERO setting changes***, it won't be there.

I'm trying to determine if I got a lemon or if I just don't know how to use it.  I haven't experienced the noise in the recording when using the XLR inputs.

I've provided a [sample recording](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116330/DR-100_0056.wav) so you can hear what I'm talking about.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Good call on asking about it. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I just tested mine again to double check and even with the input totally cranked I got none of that. Was there anything else plugged into the recorder? Power? Usb? Noise cancelling headphones?

Comment: No, nothing else plugged in at all.  I was kind of curious when I opened the box because it seemed like I didn't have to go through a setup process like the manual suggested.  I'm wondering if it got returned and I got a bad one.  I will probably exchange it just to find out.

Comment: As an FYI, I've gone ahead requested an exchange from Amazon.  I'll report back on Thursday and post whether or not I have better luck.

Comment: I just got the 100 mkII and am having the same exact problem! Did the exchanged unit work as it was supposed to? I get the buzz while recording and on playback via the machine, but if I download the audio to a computer, it is not on the file. So it's clearly a machine issue. (Does it both through the speaker and headphones.) Makes it impossible to know what you're really recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your unit needs to be repaired. If you still have the warranty, I would send it back to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like an odd / obvious thing to ask, but are you using it near a computer / any other electrical appliance?

I use a z00m H4n and I find the mics on it to be so sensitive that it picks up the sound of my (relativley) silent Imac running in the background - Which to a condenser mic sounds like a jet engine.

If you are using near any other appliance like a desktop, a laptop... anything really, turn them all off and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that if my cell phone was near the tascam, it caused a buzzing static sound. Move your phone away, and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Hi Kayte, if you listen to the sound file, it is not the interference a mobile phone makes.